# Does Update Manager show updates for software in PPAs?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, dpkg

I'm new to ubuntu, and I have some basic knowledge of how it works.

I have a question about PPAs, and installing an application/program/script via PPA. When I add a PPA to the system, and install the software packages it contains in my Ubuntu, will Update Manager show updates for that software? I think it does but I want to make sure.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Manager will show it, but only when it next attempts to retrieve update information.

Typically when you add a PPA to your sources, what happens is your computer treats that as any other repository.  If it has a higher version number than what's in the normal Ubuntu repositories, it'll supersede whatever's in the repositories and that'll be the "updated" version.

If the version in the Ubuntu repositories is newer than what's in the PPA, then you have to manually tell Ubuntu "I don't want what's in the Ubuntu repositories, I want this specific version from this specific location." and then it will install that version from the PPA specifically.  (Typically, you either have to use Synaptic, or a long command entered into Terminal, to "force" lower version numbers to be installed)

However, this is still dependent on automatic update checking through `update-manager`.  To force the update, you can open that and do "Check for Updates" which will effectively force `apt` and `dpkg` to pull new data from the repositories and the PPA, and update available software.

---

Do also note, that if the PPA is stale (i.e. not updated by its owner/maintainer anymore) you won't see any updates from the PPA.  Updated packages in a PPA, as well, will only be available if the maintainer of the PPA uploads new packages.

---

The above also makes the assumption you added the PPA, then either used Synaptic, Software Center, or a command entered in the Terminal (command line, such as `sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME`) to install the program in the PPA.  After its installed, `apt` and `update-manager` will correctly check for updates on that package from the PPA and the main repository sources.

If you didn't actually install the script and/or program that's in the PPA, then the system won't get updates for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll be aware of this PPAs and see which ones are maintained/updated. Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, @Ricbermo.  Since this answer helped you, remember to accept this as an answer when the system lets you do so in however long it says, so that you can mark the question as resolved.  Otherwise, people think your question isn't actually answered.  :)

Comment: Yes I did it. I'm a programmer and use stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Ricbermo Awesome!  I always make certain assumptions with low-rep users, though, so forgive me for posting that (it's more or less a form-letter comment)